# How do I print out all of the columns from a row in a database in C#

Tags: c#, sql

How can you print out all of the columns returned in a single row from a database. I can print a defined number by manually adding code for each column as shown below, and this is working fine for this example with only the first 3 columns. But the table has *many* columns.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);
}
```

How can I dynamically print each columns value without having to write up to reader[n]? Is there a way to loop through. I have tried using a for loop but I get an error stating trying to Read() when there is nothing to read. (or words to that affect)

Comment: I'm sure you can query the database for the columns in the table and then dynamically build your string.  (Hint: Search for that solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", reader[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", reader));
}
```

the static method `string.Join()` will take an array of objects, invoke ToString() on them, and insert the provided string between them, for any size.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

That just prints out "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader"

Answer (score 0):

Try this link . The object stated should help you to get the desired results.

http://www.thinqlinq.com/default/consuming-a-datareader-with-linq